# Get Specific Template Part if Custom Field is Some Value

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, get-template-part

I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it. I tried some solutions but I failed since I am not good programer.
I also tried to find a solution, but there is no similar question asked.
So... here is the problem.

I have a custom post type called "Arrangements", and one of the custom fields associated with that CPT is select box called "Nights" (**rtm_nights**), with options:

- no nights
- 1 night
- 2 nights
- 3 nights

In my **single-arrangements.php** there is a **get_template_part** function that call **content-arrangements.php**, and now I made 4 similar files, because I need to reorganize arrangements template:

- content-oneday.php
- content-twoday.php
- content-threeday.php
- content-fourday.php

Now... what do I need is to get some of these content templates depending of what is chosen in rmt_nights field.

- If "no nights" is chosen  **content-oneday.php** should be called via get_tempalte_part.
- If "1 night" is chosen  **content-twoday.php** should be called via get_tempalte_part.
- If "2 nights" is chosen  **content-threeday.php** should be called via get_tempalte_part.
- If "3 nights" is chosen  **content-fourday.php** should be called via get_tempalte_part.

I tried something like this in different versions but it is obviously a wrong approach:

```
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rtm_nights', '3 nights') ) ; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'fourday' ); ?>
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rtm_nights', '2 nights') ) ; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'threeday' );  ?>
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rtm_nights', '1 night') ) ; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'twoday' );  ?>
<?php if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rtm_nights', 'no nights') ) ; ?>
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'oneday' );  ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a PHP question, and not related to WordPress, but I'm answering because you are messing with codes. Just make it easy, and you also can go through it. :)

```
<?php
/**
*  get your custom field data and store into a variable
*  to make it easy - nothing else
*/
$my_custom_field = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'rtm_nights', $single=true );

if ( $my_custom_field == '3 nights' ) {
    get_template_part( 'content', 'fourday' );
} else if ( $my_custom_field == '2 nights' ) {
    get_template_part( 'content', 'threeday' );
} else if ( $my_custom_field == '1 night' ) {
    get_template_part( 'content', 'twoday' );
} else if ( $my_custom_field == 'no nights') {
    get_template_part( 'content', 'oneday' );
} //endif
?>
```

#### EDIT

And you are missing something about [**`get_post_meta()`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) syntax:

```
<?php get_post_meta( $post_id, $key, $single ); ?>
```

Value cannot be checked through it. :)

Comment: Thank you Mayeenul. This is working exactly as I wanted.

Comment: Pleasure that helped you. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is a syntax question, not really a wordpress one. However:

According to the [`get_post_meta()` Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta), the third argument is used to

> return a single result, as a **string**

if it is `true` and not to make a comparison.

You have to get the custom field and check its value.

```
if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rtm_nights') == '3 nights' ) {
  get_template_part( 'content', 'fourday' );
} else if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rtm_nights') == '2 nights' ) {
  get_template_part( 'content', 'threeday' );
} else if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rtm_nights') == '1 nights' ) {
  get_template_part( 'content', 'twoday' );
} else if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'rtm_nights') == 'no nights' ) {
  get_template_part( 'content', 'oneday' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lucio. I aslo test your solution but it breaks my template. However, thank you for the support.